# Event Sourcing: Undo Redo

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm developing an application that produces "files" that are ultimately just a list of groups of transactions: an event store. I was wondering if there was a name for the way I'm handling undo/redo. Or if there's another common way to implement such functionality.

For example, a file with three "nodes" might look something like this:

```
"transactionGroups": [
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 132,
        "length": 435,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 144,
        "length": 363,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 163,
        "length": 311,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the spirit of "[there is no delete](https://github.com/eventstore/eventstore/wiki/Event-Sourcing-Basics#there-is-no-delete)", I have devised a way to implement undo/redo by adding an "undo" transaction that references a transaction relative to its position in the store. Basically, it tells the file builder to ignore a referenced transaction when constructing the current state of the file.

To redo an operation, an undo transaction is just undone again.

```
"transactionGroups": [
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 132,
        "length": 435,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 144,
        "length": 363,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "nodeAdded",
        "frame": 0,
        "rotation": 163,
        "length": 311,
        "scale": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  // Undoes the last two transactions
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "undo",
        "transaction": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "undo",
        "transaction": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  // Redoes the last two undo transactions
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "undo",
        "transaction": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isUserOwned": true,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "op": "undo",
        "transaction": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: hmm this seems bad. surely you should 'undo' with a real transaction. in this case 'nodeRemoved' undoing us different from not doing

Comment: @Ewan I thought about doing that, but it would make undo/redo much more complicated because every group of transactions would also need to have a programmed inverse action. Is this approach bad because event stores should only look forward? Some other reason(s)? Feel free to answer this question with an explanation to why this approach is less than adequate.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't explicitly mark redos as redos.  Right now undoing is not idempotent which leads to significant issues between concurrent writers (and even for a single writer). It's also not clear to me how this would interact with checkpointing. Having an undo/redo be an inverse transaction doesn't have an issue with checkpointing.  Checkpointing, admittedly, isn't an issue if the "groups" are intended to be processed atomically.

Comment: In a different vein, what happens if you undo something that other transactions depend on?  Those dependencies may (in fact, appear) not to be explicit, i.e. you may undo a transaction whose result was the basis for the code to choose to produce one transaction instead of another.

Comment: @DerekElkins Fair points: inability to apply a checkpoint after every action will make this harder to optimize. And undoing a depended on operation could be bad (the file builder will assume this is the case because the goal is to have this handle multiple users doing potentially conflicting transactions). It's starting to sound like this approach doesn't have a name because there are many tradeoffs...

Comment: The act of undoing is generally not as simple as ignoring a portion of the past. The only way what you did could work is that if you only ever allow to undo transactions from the most recent to the oldest. An undo/redo event should only ever affect it's previous transaction. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Also, a redo would have to cause the entire file state to be destroyed and restored as you cannot re-apply past events in the future.

Comment: While the history would definitely be harder to reconstruct and read (you have to process undo vs redos first and then apply the events from the beginning), the approach seems to most efficient in terms of storage space, but not efficient in terms of performance. Could you explain the inability to checkpoint? Not sure that I see what you mean.

Comment: @plalx My concerns with checkpointing weren't so much with the checkpointing itself per se, but more with the ability or lack thereof of truncating the log after a checkpoint.  By performing a series of undos/redos, I can make any historical transaction relevant, so I can never discard any transaction ever.